# Upgrading old .Net 1.1 Windows Service to 3.5, do I need to uninstall/new install?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, windows-services, upgrade, .net-1.1

I've upgraded the solution from .Net 1.1 to .Net 3.5 in Visual Studio, and it re-compiles with no errors.  The old 1.1 Windows Service is already installed on the Windows Server 2008 R2.  Will I need to completely uninstall the old service, or can I just overwrite with the new files, please?  We will be uninstalling 1.1 from the server after all of the old apps are upgraded to 3.5.

FYI, yes I know that 1.1 on 2008R2 is bad and not officially supported (not my choice).

Comment: Since you're upgrading why not go straight to 4.0 or 4.5?

Comment: I have pushed for that to, no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you have an installer for the service.

Uninstall the service. There will be no need to uninstall .NET 1.1.